# For a custom magento module, is it ideal to store images in a similar database/filesystem structure to how Magento does it?

Tags: magento

I searched for an image's file name in my mysql database for Magento, and I couldn't find it. Also the images are stored inside alphabetical folders as well as a cache folder.

Should I do the same for my Magento module? Is there any existing code in the Magento core that I should re-use?

If not, I'll stick to storing the image's file name in the database, and all uploads going in one folder without subfolders.

Now that I think about it, it's time for question number 2. *Where should modules upload images to?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create my own database tables to save the path to images, and i save images on yourstore/media/youmodule/image
Magento sometimes make things difficult, try make your way sometimes its more easy n spend low time.